# Why is the definition of intersection multiplicity independent of choice of homogeneous coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am using the following definition of intersection multiplicity of two algebraic curves $\mathcal C, \mathcal D$ of degrees $m,d$ without common components in $\Bbb P^2(\Bbb K)$: Let $P \in \mathcal C \cap \mathcal D$, and choose any system of homogeneous coordinates such that $[0:0:1] \notin \mathcal C \cup \mathcal D$ and $P$ is the only point of $\mathcal C \cap \mathcal D$ on the line connecting $P$ and $[0:0:1]$.

Then if $\mathcal C = [F]$ and $\mathcal D = [G]$, we denote by $\operatorname{Res} (F,G,x_2)$ the resultant of $F$ and $G$ w.r.t. the variable $x_2$. If $P = [c_0:c_1:c_2]$, we define the intersection multiplicity of $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ at $P$ as the multiplicity of $[c_0, c_1]$ as a root of $\operatorname{Res} (F,G,x_2)$.

I suppose that to check that the definition is independent of the chosen system of homogeneous coordinates (as long as it satisfies the requirements of the first paragraph), I have to show that a projectivity $\psi$ taking one system of coordinates into the other won't affect the multiplicity of $\pi (\psi ([c_0:c_1:c_2]))$ as a root of $\operatorname{Res} (\psi (F),\psi(G),\psi(x_2))$, where $\pi$ is the projection onto the first two coordinates. Is there a less painful way of checking this?

Comment: Dear Rodrigo, Are you committed to this definition of intersection multiplicity?  There are other, more conceptual, definitions, that make the independence pretty obvious.  Perhaps the best thing to do is to work with one of them, and, if necessary, show that it is equivalent to this more concrete desription in terms of resultants.  Regards,